# Why does windows form resize on a different computer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-forms-designer

I have a form that I have sized to what I wanted, it has a few panels, some buttons and some labels on it but when I open it on a different computer, it is resized and it is larger.  I am using visual studio 2008.  I know this is very little detail but I thought maybe someone knows of a known issue or some troubleshooting steps that I can take.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible reasons for this are different screen resolution and different DPI.

Comment: I have a feeling that you are right so is there a generic solution so this does not cause issues on different screen sizes and different DPI?

Answer (score 2):

Several possible reasons.  First and foremost is the form's AutoScaleMode property.  The default, Font, ensures that both the font and the controls get resized to leave enough room for any displayed text.  Text size is measured in points, 1/72 of an inch.  If you run your program on a machine with a larger dots-per-inch setting for the video adapter, the fonts grow accordingly and need more pixels.  That needs the controls to be bigger as well to prevent clipping the text.

Another reason is user preferences for border width (Aero) and caption bar height.  A form is sized based on its designed ClientSize, the actual Size at runtime will be determined by adding those preferences to the design size.  That's very rarely a problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be the computers have different screen resolution and that's why it appears small in one and large on the other computer

Answer (score 0):

Diffeent resolutions, different browsers, different versions. If you want o keep this from happening, you must specify their width and height.

Comment: I do specify width and height, this code is the submitted through svn, I open it on the "bad" computer and it's bigger again.